# Android Studio 1.1.0 import libGDX project

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

I am trying to import a ligGDX a simple project(imagine it as the hello world in Java not something special). Here is what I am talking about.

[image: libGDX]

I change all the fields and the file of the project is being created. Next I am trying to import in android studio,but I am getting the folloing message.

[image: image2]

How to change that gladle version? What should I do?
[image: error message]

Thank you,

Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find your Android SDK path and put in put in "Libgdk Project Generator window":

Find SDK using Android Studio "Project Structure" window:

[image]

Second on welcome window select:

> **Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.)**

[image]

Then on explorer window navigate or type to your project location:

> **c:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\test**

[image]